# SQL Update to increment existing fields

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have an SQL table called 'Sales'

I have the fields

```
ShopID int 
TotalSalesValue numeric(18.2)
```

Contents

```
ShopID | TotalSalesValue
 1     | 10.34
 2     | 100
```

I have a stored procedure where I pass in the ShopID and addistion sales. What this does is check if the Shop ID exists in the table and if it does not, then it INSERTS into the table. If it goes exists I issue the UPDATE command. However, It update comment replaces the existing value, what I want to do it add onto the existing TotalSalesValue, a += if you may.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean how do you add to an existing value? this is similar to how its done in many languages:

```
UPDATE Sales
    TotalSalesValue = TotalSalesValue + @AdditionalValue
WHERE 
    ShopID = @ShopID
```

Comment: @gordantronThanks, i got the answer just after i posted the question and it worked, So I posted the answer then i see you also posted the answer. you speedy response it noted an appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use an "Instead of" Trigger - Check the inserted ShopID against the table shopID and then make a variable e.g. @TotalSales be filled with the old and new value e.g.

```
Set @TotalSales = (select TotalSalesValue + i.TotalSalesValue 
from table t join inserted i on t.ShopID = i.ShopID)
```

Then you perform an update to the table with new value e.g.

```
Update table
Set TotalSalesValue = @TotalSales
Where ShopID = (select ShopID from inserted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Silly me, i found the answer it was

[TotalSalesValue] = [TotalSalesValue] + @PassedinValue

hope this helps someone else who comes across this post